# why does XeLaTeX core dump?

Tags: xetex

I run an older version of Ubuntu. I have installed the latest (2020) version of TeXlive (1386-linux). If I try to run `xelatex` I get the response `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Several questioners say that they use `xelatex` but I cannot do that while trying to answer their problem.

So, how can I use `xelatex`?

Comment: Quite likely a mismatch of libraries.

Comment: @egreg Maybe. But if so shouldn't TeXlive ensure compatible libraries knowing what my OS is? If not, how do I find out what the mismatches are, and how to correct that? Mind you I never use `xelatex` for my own work, only when trying to help SE questioners, so I'm not particularly bothered.

Comment: No, the precompiled binaries cannot consider every combination of every possible version of every platform. You can recompile the source on your machine, though.